# Why FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python

```
debian8@debian:~$ ls -al /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 debian8 debian8 15 Jun 19 18:58 /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock -> 127.0.1.1:+2815
```

The file `/home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock` is a link.

```
debian8@debian:~$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
>>> import os
>>> file1="/tmp/.X0-lock"
>>> print(os.stat(file1))
os.stat_result(st_mode=33060, st_ino=8126472, st_dev=2050, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=11, st_atime=1497877067, st_mtime=1497868886, st_ctime=1497868886)
>>> file2="/home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock"
>>> print(os.stat(file2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock'
```

Why `os.stat` can't get infos on file2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the file it is linked **to** exist? os.stat() follows symlinks. If you want to stat the link file, you need os.lstat()

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you don't have permission to open this file.try `sudo chmod 777 /home/debian8/.mozilla/firefox/3usaclqf.default/lock`